# using a mustinherit property in base class

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop

I have a base class Table with a default mustoverride property Rows that i want to have in all derived classes.

```
Public MustInherit Class TableBase
  Default Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Rows(iID As Integer) As RowBase
End Class
```

With ofcourese the rowbase class

```
Public Class RowBase
End Class
```

A class derived from rowbase named RowX

```
Public Class RowX
    Inherits RowBase
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

A table class TableX derived from Table base.

```
Public Class TableX
    Inherits TableBase

    Default Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Rows(iID As Integer) As RowBase
        Get
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And a test form with a method with:

```
_test = _tableX(2).Name
```

Building this would give me the message that name is not a property of Rowbase.
I cant change the type of the property Rows in tableX to RowX because it is mustinherit.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`RowX` should be a property of `TableX`  as a table "has-a" row.

And the property `Name` should not be `public` make it `private` and have getter and setter methods as `public` since it violates encapsulation

So now `Name` can  be accessed using `_tablex._rowx.Name`.
Hence you can modify the code to:

```
Public MustInherit Class TableBase
  public property row As RowBase
  Default Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Rows(iID As Integer) As RowBase
End Class

Default Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Rows(iID As Integer) As RowBase
    row.Name=iTD
    End Get
End Property
```

Assuming you want to set the value passed as name.

Sorry for wrong syntaxes if any as im a Java developer